# Excel VBA - Add row & make active

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening

Please see the attached image for an example of my data.  The strings in column A are grouped together.

[image]

The below code is a WIP to achieve the following...

1. Find the last occurrence of each delivery location & add a new row after.
2. In the newly created row, in the columns named Header11-14, add a formula to total the values in the above rows
3. Do some formatting

So far it adds the new row after each delivery location but what I can't figure out is how to add the sum formula.  I know how to add the string but I can't figure out how to reference the cells above...

[image]

The image above what i'm trying to achieve.

```
Sub insertRow_totals()
Dim changeRow, counter As Integer

counter = 2

While Cells(counter, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(counter, 1) <> Cells(counter - 1, 1) Then
        Rows(counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        counter = counter + 2
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Wend

Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, why not just use the subtotals? [Read about them here](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 

The data will be pulled from Access and may vary in length.  The groupings will vary in size.

Comment: I agree with @vacip. Use Subtotals. Record a macro for subtotals. Simply amend the code so that works on realtime data of varying lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to count how many rows with the same name there are (or remember the row index of the first one), then something like this should work

```
Sub insertRow_totals()
Dim changeRow, counter As Integer

counter = 2
FirstRow = 2

While Cells(counter, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(counter, 1) <> Cells(counter - 1, 1) Then
        Rows(counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    For i = 11 To 14
        ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(FirstRow, i).Address & ":" & Cells(counter - 1, i).Address & ")"
    Next i

    counter = counter + 1
    FirstRow = counter
End If
    counter = counter + 1
Wend

Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```